# How to create a commons-net FTPClient from a URL

Tags: java, ftp

Is there a way to construct an [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) instance from a URL such as `ftp://user:pass@foo.bar:2121/path`, similar to [FtpURLConnection](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/www/protocol/ftp/FtpURLConnection.java.html) in the JDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is the parsing then use the code below to parse and then just create a wrapper class ...

> import java.net.*; import java.io.*;
>
> public class ParseURL {
>       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>           URL aURL = new URL("http://java.sun.com:80/docs/books/tutorial"
>                              + "/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");
>           System.out.println("protocol = " + aURL.getProtocol());
>       System.out.println("authority = " +
>           aURL.getAuthority());
>           System.out.println("host = " + aURL.getHost());
>           System.out.println("port = " + aURL.getPort());
>           System.out.println("path = " + aURL.getPath());
>           System.out.println("query = " + aURL.getQuery());
>           System.out.println("filename = " + aURL.getFile());
>           System.out.println("ref = " + aURL.getRef());
>       } }

Here's the output displayed by the program:
protocol = http
authority = java.sun.com:80
host = java.sun.com
port = 80
path = /docs/books/tutorial/index.html
query = name=networking
filename = /docs/books/tutorial/index.html?name=networking
ref = DOWNLOADING

Comment: There's a bunch of issues to deal with, though: if the port's omitted, we have to use the defaultPort; getUserInfo() might return nothing, just a user, or a user and a password.

Comment: @hertzspring These are issues you'd have to deal with anyway. You can see in http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/www/protocol/ftp/FtpURLConnection.java.html that e.g. default port is grabbed from `FtpClient.defaultPort()`. It's very simple to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct constructor available for it,
You can use something

```
FTPClient f = new FTPClient();
    f.connect(server);
    f.login(username, password);
```

Comment: Yes, but this involves parsing username, password, port, host and path by hand.  I was hoping to avoid having to do that.

Comment: Yes I could understand. :) , but you can easily parse it